# Spirit of the Elder Lizard or Spirit of the Spectral Wraith on jungle Evelynn?

Tags: league-of-legends

Are they certain situations I would get one item over the other? Also, what are the pros/cons of picking either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Other than stats, there is one important thing to consider about the respective jungling items: their passives.

[Spirit of the Elder Lizard](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Spirit_of_the_Elder_Lizard) provides additional damage on basic attacks and non-DoT (damage over time) spells. This is extremely helpful for junglers with fast attacks speeds, like Udyr, or those with spammable abilities, like Evelynn. Each time you hit an enemy with your Q, you will deal small amounts of true damage. With the additional 10% cooldown reduction granted by the item, you can do a lot of sustained damage.

On the other hand, [Spirit of the Spectral Wraith](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Spirit_of_the_Spectral_Wraith) provides for slightly more durability with 20% spell vamp and added revenue with the decreased cooldown on Smite. This is very useful in the case that you are unable to run a good ganking game, either through enemy team comp or skill.

All in all, which item you pick is up to your playstyle. If you're a good ganker and find yourself getting a kill early, pick up Elder Lizard by all means. It will make your ganking power all the more stronger. If you instead find yourself unable to gank, you can make up for that lack of gold with the Spectral Wraith.

Comment: Playstyle maybe but if you pick evelyn the goal is to gank and apply pressure not stay safe and farm your jungle like some other junglers. I always pick SotEL cause with the Attack speed buff from E and the passiv you can steal a buff VERY VERY fast and for ganking the true damage on Q is just insane at low level

Comment: @Yuki With the preseason update (patch 3.14/pi) how has this changed?

Comment: @DomenikVanBuskirk Most likely. I'll need some time to look for over the new changes and do some testing before I push an update.

Answer (score 1):

Each item supports a different build, as one is AP and one is AD. In general, you should pick in order to complement your runes, masteries, and team composition (having 3 champs of one damage type and 2 of the other is ideal). Both are reasonable since they offer damage and sustain for jungling

Comment: think he means the items spirit of the elder lizard, spirit of the spectral wraith not the camps

Comment: That makes more sense.